# Inverse Poisson pmf

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let's have a random variable $\mathcal{X}$ whose pmf is the Poisson distribution
$$
f(k;\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}
$$

I was wondering on how to determine the pmf of a variable defined as $\mathcal{Y}=1/\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: You can’t, because $Y$ isn’t defined for $X=0$.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't be sufficient to just start the sum from 1 and simply add  Pr(X=0) to that?